# How to migrate to Serverless (Cloud Formation) to AWS CDK (Cloud Development Kit)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-cdk

I've got a big-ass Serverless project and I wonder if matching the cloud formation template schema with CDK would do the trick, or is there something extra to the process.

Comment: What do you mean by `I wonder if matching the cloud formation template schema with CDK would do the trick`?

Comment: @AmitBaranes I mean replicating what's been declared in CloudFormation, with CDK (typescript) and then publish it as the same stack. Will AWS simply accept it?

Comment: Short answer - No. Long answer - CDK generates new id for each resource that created, therefore, new resources are created. Currently, we must create a side to side stacks and later migrate relevant data between them.

Comment: Are your resources manually named? If so, porting it over to CDK should be doable. –– We often recommend using Serverless Framework and AWS CDK together. Serverless’s strength is working with Lambda and API Gateway. So a good pattern here is to use CDK for the rest of your infrastructure, and Serverless for your Lambda functions. –– We created a tool to do exactly this - Serverless Stack Toolkit (SST), which allows you to combine CDK and Serverless Framework - https://github.com/serverless-stack/serverless-stack –– So you can do `sls deploy --stage dev` and `sst deploy --stage dev`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to deploy a CDK app to an existing CloudFormation stack, although it would be very difficult to achieve for non-trivial stacks since CDK apps usually involve many resources.

The `cdk diff` command will be your best friend. You can name your stack in the CDK app using the same name as the existing stack:

```
MyExistingStack(app, 'my-existing-stack')
```

Then you can iteratively add/remove resources and run `cdk diff` to check your success in matching the current deployment. CDK will additionally create metadata resources that will be added to the stack in addition to the currently existing resources.

Matching resource names can be difficult. CDK automatically names many of the resources in a way that will not match you existing stack. Following the instructions on [CDK Escape Hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html), you can access lower level CFN Resources directly and modify the name.

> If a Construct is missing a feature or you are trying to work around an issue, you can modify the CFN Resource that is encapsulated by the Construct.
>
> All Constructs contain within them the corresponding CFN Resource. For example, the high-level Bucket construct wraps the low-level CfnBucket construct. Because the CfnBucket corresponds directly to the AWS CloudFormation resource, it exposes all features that are available through AWS CloudFormation.
>
> The basic approach to get access to the CFN Resource class is to use construct.node.defaultChild (Python: default_child), cast it to the right type (if necessary), and modify its properties.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this, and yes, CDK adds a random string at the end of the resource ids, giving us no way to match with the old resource ids. Real bummer. `RestHandler1LambdaFunction -> RestHandler1LambdaFunction6086A952`

Comment: I figured it out. [Add this](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/207#issuecomment-515507159) to your answer so that I may re-accept it.